# Get Android Emojis code

Tags: android, emoji

I receive from a webservice emojis like **\ud83d  \ude48   \ud83d**  and I really don't have any problem to display them or send it between activities using this library (https://github.com/Will5/EMOJITextView)

The thing is that when I type a content with Emojis and the content is sent to a server, I need to send them encoded.
So what I do is to get encoding of each one, but the result is not the expected. (**\u263a  \u1f60A   \u1f600  \uDe01 <---  this codes doesn't work**)

**How I can get the real encoding of an emoji typed in  an EditText?**

Answer (score 1):

You will need a customised EditText for this purpose too. Cause built in editText cannot handle such kind of encoding. The library link you gave already has a custom editText defined as below

```
public class EmojiEditText extends EditText {

public EmojiEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public EmojiEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EmojiEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public final String getTextWithEmojis() {
    return EmojiHandler.encodeJava(this.getText().toString());
}

public final void setTextWithEmojis(String text) {
    this.setText(EmojiHandler.decodeJava(text));
}

}
```

And the emoji handler resides [here](https://github.com/Will5/EMOJITextView/blob/master/EMOJITextView/src/may/will/emojitextview/EmojiHandler.java)

So, you can easily use that editText for getting emoji input. Also get encoded emoji from it.

Comment: I use EmojiEditText, but nothing, here is the visual example.

[link](http://i68.tinypic.com/108ck86.jpg)

And the result after get Endoded is  **\u263A\u1F60A\u1F600\u1F601\uDE01**  <--- This codes are nothing and 1 emoji it's been lost...

Comment: i dont get your point.. can you say what s the problem you are facing? why  the term encoded is coming here? whatever you get from edittext u send it. no need to encode